# Java security policy restrict RuntimePermission exitVM

Tags: java, security, jvm

I want to restrict my JVM to exit vm via policy file but it's not working. Can you guys please help my how to restict access in java.io.RuntimePermission?

```
grant {
    permission java.io.RuntimePermission "exitVM", "none";
};
```

Comment: You grant permissions rather than deny them (under this API). You've presumably not enabled the `SecurityManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the javodoc for [RuntimePermission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimePermission.html):

> This class is for runtime permissions. A RuntimePermission contains a
>   name (also referred to as a "target name") but no actions list; you
>   either have the named permission or you don't.

Thus, the "none" action is incorrect in your permission setting.

Regarding the `exitVM` permission:

> **Permission Target Name**: exitVM.{exit status}
>
> **What the Permission Allows**: Halting of the Java Virtual Machine with the specified exit status
>
> **Risks of Allowing this Permission**: This allows an attacker to mount a denial-of-service attack by automatically forcing the virtual
>   machine to halt. Note: The "exitVM.*" permission is automatically
>   granted to all code loaded from the application class path, thus
>   enabling applications to terminate themselves. Also, the "exitVM"
>   permission is equivalent to "exitVM.*".

Thus a valid syntax for the permission name is either of "exitVM", "exitVM.*", "exitVM.n" (where n designates an exit code).

The problem here is that, as stated in the doc, ***the "exitVM.*" permission is automatically granted to all code loaded from the application class path***. So if the code which calls System.exit(...) is in the main classpath that is setup on the java command line, you cannot prevent it from working. This would not be the case if, for instance, the code calling System.exit(...) was loaded from a separate class loader.

Also keep in mind that a `grant` statement is for *granting* permissions, not for *denying* them. According to this, the only way to deny the "exitVM" permission is to *never grant it*.

Comment: But by default it's granted! How can I deny access to System.exit in my code?